# TensorFlow: Can "None" in gradients be automatically replaced with zeros or used in an optimizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used `tf.stop_gradient()` to turn off the gradient calculation for some of the weights in my neural network. Unfortunately, `tf.GradientTape().gradient()` assigns the gradient for those weights as `None`, which does not work with `optimizer.apply_gradients`. The workaround is to afterwards assign zeros to those gradients.

Is there a better work around?

Is it possible to have `tf.GradientTape().gradient()` automatically replace `None` with zeros? Alternatively, is there a way to get the optimizer to work with `None` in the gradients list?

Comment: You should definite check the documentation and see if there is something there that can help: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient specifically for the gradient function.

Comment: Yup, its there. I got stuck looking at tf.GradientTape's properties.  I should have looked more thoroughly under `.gradient()`  instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are turning off the gradients for some weights, `GradientTape().gradient()` automatically sets the gradient for those weights to be `None` which are not compatible with an optimizer. However, they can be replaced by zeros by setting `unconnected_gradients` as such:

`tape.gradient(loss, weights, unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)`

This is then compatible with the optimizer.